# Spherical Mapping in Fragment Shader

Tags: rendering, shader, projection

So, I'm trying to create something like a SkySphere - an inverted sphere, situated at infinity, with a texture smoothly mapped onto it.

However, I'm having some trouble getting the spherical coordinate mapping down. I've tried all sorts of mappings, including latitude/longitude mappings, but they always seem to create this asymptotic behaviour as I rotate around my scene (images zipping around rather than being correctly mapped to a sphere). I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong.

```
#version 120
uniform sampler2D iChannel0;

uniform vec3 direction;

#define PI 3.141592653
#define TWOPI (2*PI)

void main()
{

    vec3 offset = vec3(gl_TexCoord[0].xy-0.5,0)*2;
    vec3 d = normalize(direction + offset);
    vec2 tx = vec2(0.5 + atan(d.z, sqrt(d.x*d.x + d.y*d.y))/TWOPI, 0.5 + atan(d.y, d.x)/TWOPI);

    vec4 c = texture2D( iChannel0, tx);

    gl_FragColor = c*gl_Color;
}
```

This is my shader currently, and it's producing this extremely strange behaviour.

To clarify, I'm not rendering this on an actual sphere, but a simple quad which I'm intending to project a spherical-like image onto. There are a number of reasons I'm working this way rather than just using an actual inverted sphere.

Can anyone help me work out exactly why my shader is behaving so strangely?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I did a stupid. The problem was that my `offset` value was computed in camera space, but being applied in world space. I simply had to multiple the x and y values by the right and up vectors of the camera before applying, and it all works perfectly.